# Redimensionar imagem em um quadrado mantendo proporção da imagem original PHP

Tags: php, xml, resize, image, gd

O que acontece é o seguinte: estou puxando algumas fotos de produtos de um link XML, e as imagens vem em diferentes tamanhos.

Atualmente uso um código que pega a imagem e redimensiona para 200x200, porém imagens com altura e largura diferentes obviamente que ficam estranhas.

```
$img_path     = (string) $googleBase->image_link;

$destination  = $img_server_folder_path;

$stlName = "stl";

$dimensions = getimagesize($img_path);

$w = $dimensions[0];
$h = $dimensions[1];

$ratios = [
    'small' => 200/$w
];

$resource = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $img_path ) );

foreach ( $ratios as $name => $ratio ) {

$w2 = $w * $ratio;
$h2 = round($h * $ratio);

$output = imagecreatetruecolor($w2, $h2);

if ( ! file_exists( $img_server_folder_path . $row['NomeLoja'] ) ) {
    mkdir( $img_server_folder_path .    $row['NomeLoja'], 0777, true );
}

// definimoso caminho no servidor para salvar a imagem | evita erro de acesso a pasta
$imagem = $img_server_folder_path . $row['NomeLoja'] . "/" . $googleBase->id . "_" . $stlName . ".jpg";

imagecopyresampled($output, $resource, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w2, $h2, $w, $h);

imagejpeg($output, $imagem, 100);

imagedestroy($output);
```

O que eu preciso é criar antes um quadrado branco, com 200x200, e depois colocar nesse quadrado a imagem do produto, respeitando sua proporção mas fazendo ela inteira caber no quadrado branco, será que é possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema utilizando a biblioteca php zebra_image. Na biblioteca tem método que faz justamente o que precisava de maneira espetacular.

http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-image/